# Как добавить пустую строку в target layout в NLog.config файле?

Tags: c#, nlog

Только начал изучать `NLog` и не до конца понимаю, как работать с шаблонами вывода. При логировании в файл идет сплошной текст, а хочется добавить пустую строку при окончании записи, чтобы хоть как-то отделить сообщения друг от друга.

На данный момент мой `layout` такой:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt"
        layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message} |${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
```

Comment: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Newline-Layout-Renderer ?

Comment: @tym32167
Спасибо, выручил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как помог @tym32167, можно использовать `${newline}` в `layout` цели, после чего будет появляться пустая строка.